# NGINX FastCGI without using spawn-fcgi

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I am using NGINX's FastCGI interface.  I currently launch my backend app with spawn-fcgi.

```
spawn-fcgi -p 8000 -n fcgitest
```

"man spawn-fcgi" gives a few reasons why I should use it to launch my app.--but I am not convinced those are good reasons for me.

Is it possible to launch my app (fcgitest) directly?  For instance, that would make it easier to debug the app..

What are the downsides of launching it directly?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible and it is a convenient approach to debugging. Take a look at this brilliant two-file library [here](http://althenia.net/fcgicc). Not only it lets you run your application free of `spawn-fcgi`, but also it allows you to run it in a variety of ways suited for production.

Of course after developing your code it is recommended to launch the FastCGI application using `spawn-fcgi` as it is written it's manual page:

- Privilege separation without needing a suid-binary or running a server as root.
- You can restart your web server and the FastCGI applications without restarting the others.
- You can run them in different chroot()s.
- Running  your  FastCGI applications doesn't depend on the web server you are running, which  allows  for  easier  testing  of  other  web servers.

Comment: Can this library (fcgicc) also be used for a C application (not C++)? How?